# How to reassign task to another group

Tags: java, workflow, alfresco, activiti

I'm working on the ad-hoc task flow of Activiti in Alfresco 4.2e.

I rearranged it to my needs, and I can set in the BPMN definition the Activiti groups as follows:

```
activiti:candidateGroups="GROUP_xxxxxx"
```

I tried many ways in javascript API to reassign a UserTask to another group with no luck. I tried using `bpm_outcome` as the variable:

```
var groupName = execution.getVariable('bpm_outcome');
workflow.parameters["bpm:groupAssignee"] = people.getGroup( "GROUP_" + groupName );
```

and changing the task type:

```
  <type name="wf:submitReviewTask">
         <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>
         <mandatory-aspects>
            <aspect>bpm:groupAssignee</aspect>
         </mandatory-aspects>
      </type>
```

with the following API call found on the web:

> executionContext.setVariable("bpm_groupAssignee",people.getGroup(
>   "GROUP_" + groupName ));

I reset the workFlowModel to previous version of wf:submitReviewTask.

Now I'm stuck, can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i did it.

Basically it is enough to follow instructions that anybody can found here:

http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#bpmnUserTaskAssignment

The Activiti instruction guide simply tells how to create a custom tasklistener, after that it has to be deployed in the alfresco web\lib. 
Once done, the processdefinition file has to be signed in the right task with the package of the custom listner project and the class name itself.